# how to display a parent of an element only if it contains an attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Trying to solve a riddle. I want to display a grand parent of an element only if it contains an attribute (any attribute). Thanks in advance! I have the following code:

```
<xsl:when test="content/track">
  <xsl:for-each select="content/track">
    <div class="container_orange">
      <xsl:value-of select="./text()" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
      is <b>current</b> and grandchild of
      <b><xsl:value-of select="name(../..)"/></b> 
      <!-- displays only the name of the node that is a grandparent, but how to add an attribute condition?-->
    </div>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:when>
```

Answer (score 1):

Conditions are called predicates and go into square brackets so `../..[@*]` selects the grandparent that has any attribute.

Comment: I've tried that before and it doesn't work. Here are the files: http://makdeniss.eu/xmlremote/content.xml http://makdeniss.eu/xmlremote/content.xsl

Comment: As far as I can see all `track` elements in that sample have the same `section` grandparent that has an attribute. So the predicate is true for all `track` elements. Is that not what you expect? Which output do you want for that sample?

Comment: For now it just shows an error with your solution, but it should work. All the grandparents contain attribute now, but if I add one grandparent with out an attribute, then the above expression would only work for that one which has the attribute.

Comment: Which error do you get, which XSLT processor in which browser do you use?

Comment: I just get a blank page with Chrome and Safari. Thanks for your help so far, Martin!

Comment: I loaded http://makdeniss.eu/xmlremote/content.xml with Firefox just fine. I can confirm that Chrome displays a blank page. I don't know why.

Comment: Indeed. On firefox it works, but safari and chrome display a blank page. Strange.

Comment: I see one problem, the `link` elements should be put into the HTML `head` element that is missing. I have not tested whether that improves the rendering in Chrome.

Comment: What's more strange is that IE doesn't display any styling but displays pure xml.

Comment: I have had a further look now with IE 11 on Windows 8.1, it seems when I simply load the XML file that it does not apply the XSLT stylesheet and renders all text of the XML. If I hit F12 to open the debugging tools and reload then an error ("invalid qualified character" (my translation of an error message in German)) is suddenly indicated at line 6, column 10 of content.xml. Chrome in its error console opened with F12 also shows an error message but a completely different one related to an extension and scrollWidth. The content type headers of application/xml are fine.

Comment: I don't know where else to look, maybe someone else has an idea what goes wrong with Chrome or IE.

Comment: I think it's the problem with this expression: **name(../..[@*]**, because if I change it to just **../..** then everything works fine even on chrome and safari. Can you suggest an alternative to this expression I mean **name(../..[@*])**?